# Update Multiple Dataframe Columns From Other Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes:

`df1`

```
         Date         ID Company     Symbol  Shares  Value
0  2014-09-30   32511907     foo        NaN      10    101
1  2014-09-30   32511957     bar  No Symbol      10    101
2  2014-12-31   32511907    test  No Symbol      18    152
3  2013-06-30   32511107      AA        APC      43    373
4  2014-06-30  166764100      CC        CVX      29    381
5  2014-09-30  166764900       C  No Symbol      13    155
6  2014-09-30  166764950   C Inc  No Symbol      13    155
7  2015-09-30  475643276    Test        NaN      13    155
```

And `df2`:

```
   Company         ID     Symbol
0   AA Inc   32511907        AAA
1   AA Inc   32511957  No Symbol
2   BB Inc   32511107        APC
3  CC Corp  166764100        CVX
4   CC Inc  166764900  No Symbol
5   CC Inc  166764950  No Symbol
```

By using `ID` as the key, I need to replace `Symbol` and `Company` in `df1`, with those in `df2`, so that the output looks like:

```
         Date         ID Company     Symbol  Shares  Value
0  2014-09-30   32511907  AA Inc        AAA      10    101
1  2014-09-30   32511957  AA Inc  No Symbol      10    101
2  2014-12-31   32511907  AA Inc        AAA      18    152
3  2013-06-30   32511107  BB Inc        APC      43    373
4  2014-06-30  166764100 CC Corp        CVX      29    381
5  2014-09-30  166764900  CC Inc  No Symbol      13    155
6  2014-09-30  166764950  CC Inc  No Symbol      13    155
7  2015-09-30  475643276    Test        NaN      13    155
```

I have tried:

```
df = df1.set_index('ID')
df.update(df2.set_index('ID'))
df = df1.loc[df1.Symbol == '', ['Company', 'Symbol']] = df.reset_index()
```

But when performed on the full dataset, I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` because line `df.update(df2.set_index('ID'))` makes `ID` the index, which results in a few duplicates.

So are there any alternatives to achieving the desired output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message. In any case, I would look into merging, see for example https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html.

Comment: if in `df2` you have twice the same `ID`, which row you want to use for updating `df1`?

Comment: Which rows in `df2` have the same `ID`?

Comment: @MSD the error you get is because in your real dataframe `df2`, you have at least two rows with the same ID, for `df1` is does not matter

Comment: I don't think so because when I do `dupes = d2f[df2.duplicated()]`, I get an empty dataframe.

Comment: @MSD I'm just talking about duplicates the ID column, so try `df2['ID'].shape[0]` and `df2['ID'].drop_duplicates().shape[0]`?

Comment: Yep that's it. I feel like an idiot... thanks a ton.

Comment: @MSD sometimes when coding you can't see the silly mistakes because you are too close of it :) have fun coding!

Answer (score 0):

A pd.merge can solve this. Assume you only want IDs in df1

```
result = pd.merge(left=df1[['Date', 'ID', 'Shares', 'Values']], 
                  right=df2, on=['ID'], how='left')
```

If you need to merge on different labels, you can use left_on and right_on.

Change the how argument to specify what IDs to keep

- keep IDs only occurred in df1 ('left')
- keep IDs only occurred in df2 ('right')
- keep **all** IDs occurred in both df1 and df2 ('outer')
- keep **only** IDs occurred in both df1 and df1 ('inner')